# How to send email on every failure except one, in jenkins job configured using yaml

Tags: jenkins, yaml, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

```
publishers:
  - test-results
  - email-ext:
      recipients: abc@gmail.com
      script: |
          def errorToSkip = "Error cloning remote repo"
          
          if (currentBuild.result == 'FAILURE' && env.ERROR_MESSAGE == errorToSkip) {
            currentBuild.result = 'SUCCESS'
          }
```

I was trying to send email on every failure except the above one which is attached in the image. But it is sending me the mail on for that failure also. Can anyone help in debugging where am I going wrong ?

[image]

Comment: post {  
    failure {  
         mail bcc: '', body: "Job failed" to: "someone@something.com";
 }